# Powershell New-Partition - Need 4th partition to be primary not extended

Tags: powershell, partitioning, powershell-4.0

I have created a script that runs in PE to create 4 partitions and apply the images.  I have posted it below for others to review, maybe copy helpful parts :).

I do however have one small problem with it.  DiskManager in Windows and Powershell automatically create the 4th partition as an extended partition instead of a "primary" partition.  This is not desired in my image for a few reasons I won't get into.

**Is there a way to create the 4th partition as a primary in Powershell without scripting to diskpart?**

*Warning the below can be very destructive!*

```
get-disk
$disknumber = Read-Host 'Please enter which disk number listed above to deploy to (ex 0):'
$getdisk=get-disk $disknumber
$drivesizedata=($getdisk.size-86213918720)/2
clear-disk $disknumber -removedata -confirm:$false
initialize-disk $disknumber -partitionstyle MBR
new-partition $disknumber -size 300MB -driveletter j
new-partition $disknumber -size 80GB -driveletter k
new-partition $disknumber -size $drivesizedata -driveletter l
new-partition $disknumber -usemaximumsize  -driveletter m
format-volume jklm -confirm:$false
dism /apply-image /imagefile:$imagepath\OS.wim /index:1 /applydir:k:\
dism /apply-image /imagefile:$imagepath\Data.wim /index:1 /applydir:l:\
dism /apply-image /imagefile:$imagepath\Backup.wim /index:1 /applydir:m:\
bcdboot /s j: /f BIOS k:\windows
Set-Partition -DriveLetter J -IsActive $True
```

Comment: after all this time, would you have a solution for this?